# Why can not show image in class variable? python tkinter canvas

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I write gui programing on python3.7.1.

when I use python tkinter canvas,I count not show image.

I use class variable for  image variable,but it can not work.
so I use instance variable, it can work.

what differ??

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image,ImageTk

class img_canvas(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,master)

        i = Image.open('./sample.png')
        w,h = i.size

        self.img_canvas1= tk.Canvas(self, width=w, height=h)
        self.img_canvas2 = tk.Canvas(self, width=w, height=h)


        tki = ImageTk.PhotoImage(i)
        self.tki = ImageTk.PhotoImage(i)

        self.img_canvas2.create_image(w/2,h/2,image=tki)
        self.img_canvas1.create_image(w/2,h/2,image=self.tki)

        self.img_canvas1.pack()
        self.img_canvas2.pack()
```

[exec result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sl9xg.png)

please.

Comment: `tki` is local variable, not class variable.  It will be destroyed once the function completed.